# Are these gpg commands identical?

Tags: gnupg

I've found `gpg -c < unencrypted_file > encrypted_file` this command from https://askubuntu.com/questions/27770/is-there-a-tool-to-encrypt-a-file-or-directory this page, but in gpg manual it says `gpg --output test.gpg --symmetric test.out` something like this. I couldn't find anything about first one is an alias on the manual page so i want to see is there a difference and tested like this:

create 500Mb file first

> `dd if=/dev/urandom of=./tmpfile bs=1000000 count=500`
>
> `time gpg -c <tmpfile> file1 (19 secs)`
>
> `time gpg --output file2 --symmetric tmpfile  (21 secs)`
>
> `time gpg --output file3 --symmetric tmpfile  (21 secs)`
>
> `time gpg -c <tmpfile> file4  (20 secs)`

second command seems a bit slower to me, is this because of coincidence or are these commands different?

edit: gpg version is 1.4.20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, these commands are effectively the same:

```
gpg -c < file > file.gpg
gpg --output file.gpg --symmetric file
```

First, `-c` is just a shorthand for `--symmetric`:

```
 -c, --symmetric             encryption only with symmetric cipher
```

Also note that the characters `<` and `>` are used in Bash for [I/O redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html), they are not part of GPG's option syntax.

What's going on here is that GPG can take input from either stdin or a file specified as an argument. Instead of giving the filename as an argument, `< FILE` just feeds it via stdin. When GPG notices that input is given via stdin, it will print the output to stdout by default instead of creating a file (unless you use `--output`). So you can just redirect stdout with `> FILE` to write the encrypted data to a target file.

Comment: ahh, < for input and > for output, i thought it's wrapping only input like <inputfilename>, thanks for reply. Can we use these i/o feeds for zip files, binary files etc or just for text files?

Comment: @rugowimola You can use `<` and `>` for arbitrary data streams, including zip files.

Comment: Thanks, one more thing but last :) i didn't find anything about spaces on this link about i/o redirection. `< input > output` causes any difference from `<input> output` ?

Comment: @rugowimola No, that should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

> second command seems a bit slower to me, is this because of coincidence or are these commands different?

They might be *equivalent in high-level functionality*, but they're clearly not identical; the two commands don't match exactly, so they're not identical.

It's no coincidence that they're equivalent in functionality, as the decision for `gpg` to use `stdin` and `stdout` couldn't possibly have been unintentional.

However, what is coincidental is that one is slower than the other. There are factors at play here such as *file buffering* which may vary in specification and performance between implementations of the C standard library let alone the POSIX terminal. Simply put, one may be slower on your computer, yet faster or equal speed on another hardware configuration, using a different compiler or standard library.

From a security standpoint (which is what this site is about), you should use whichever you're most comfortable using. I imagine the user interface designers added both interfaces to provide an alternative for shell configurations which don't support pipes, and that alone doesn't seem to pose a significant security risk.